# Developing a Continuous-time Markov Chain model to simulate the distribution (counts) of parasites on a fish in R

Tags: r, modeling, markov-chains

I am developing a (complex) CTMC model in R (as a beginner in R) to simulate the distribution of parasite load (counts) at 8 different body parts of a fish; assuming a parasite can move from one body part to another randomly. To start with a simple block of codes as below, it is able to simulate CTMC but returns errors below when trying to repeat it a number of times (for some runs).

> ```
> Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : too few positive
> probabilities
> ```

Warning message:

> ```
> In rexp(1, Qt) : NAs produced
> ```

I realized, most of the rate values in the Q (matrix) are zero and thus, sampling at such instances, returns such as error. I would like to know if there is anyway to correct this error so as to run the model a number of times without such an error.

To make it simple, I started with these piece of codes:

```
Fishsim_model <- function(b,d,m,X0,Ti){
  #b=birth rate; d=death rate; m=movement rate; Ti=finishing time
  #X0=initial distribution; X= states 
  X <- X0
  Ti <- floor(Ti)
  ti <- 0 # (initial) time
  day <- 1

 saved <- matrix(0, Ti+1, 8) #Matrix of zeros to save final results
  saved[day,] <- X0

  Q <- rep(0, 36) # vector of rates
  Qt <- 0 # Qt = sum(Q) is departure rate from current state

  while (ti < Ti){
    #Calculate rates
    Q[1]<-X[1]*b
    Q[2]<-X[2]*b
    Q[3]<-X[3]*b
    Q[4]<-X[4]*b
    Q[5]<-X[5]*b
    Q[6]<-X[6]*b
    Q[7]<-X[7]*b
    Q[8]<-X[8]*b
    Q[9]<-X[1]*d
    Q[10]<-X[2]*d
    Q[11]<-X[3]*d
    Q[12]<-X[4]*d
    Q[13]<-X[5]*d
    Q[14]<-X[6]*d
    Q[15]<-X[7]*d
    Q[16]<-X[8]*d
    Q[17]<-X[1]*m
    Q[18]<-X[3]*m/3
    Q[19]<-X[4]*m/5
    Q[20]<-X[6]*m/2
    Q[21]<-X[4]*m/5
    Q[22]<-X[5]*m/2
    Q[23]<-X[2]*m/2
    Q[24]<-X[5]*m/2
    Q[25]<-X[3]*m/2
    Q[26]<-X[2]*m/2
    Q[27]<-X[3]*m/3
    Q[28]<-X[7]*m/2
    Q[29]<-X[8]*m/2
    Q[30]<-X[4]*m/5
    Q[31]<-X[4]*m/4
    Q[32]<-X[7]*m/2
    Q[33]<-X[6]*m/2
    Q[34]<-X[8]*m/2
    Q[35]<-X[3]*m/4
    Q[36]<-X[4]*m/5 
     Qt <- sum(Q) 

    # time for next jump
    ti <- ti + rexp(1, Qt)
    # new state
    j <- sample(36, 1, prob = Q)

    if (j == 1) {
      X[1] <- X[1] + 1
    } else if (j==2){
      X[2]<- X[2]+1
    } else if (j==3){
      X[3]<-X[3]+1
    } else if (j==4){
      X[4]<-X[4]+1
    } else if (j==5){
      X[5]<-X[5]+1
    } else if (j==6){
      X[6]<-X[6]+1
    } else if (j==7){
      X[7]<-X[7]+1
    } else if (j==8){
      X[8]<-X[8]+1
    } else if (j==9){
      X[1]<-X[1]-1
    } else if (j==10){
      X[2]<-X[2]-1
    } else if (j==11){
      X[3]<-X[3]-1
    } else if (j==12){
      X[4]<-X[4]-1
    } else if (j==13){
      X[5]<-X[5]-1
    } else if (j==14){
      X[6]<-X[6]-1
    } else if (j==15){
      X[7]<-X[7]-1
    }else if (j==16){
      X[8]=X[8]-1
    } else if (j==17){
      X[1]=X[1]-1
      X[3]=X[3]+1
    } else if (j==18){
      X[1]=X[1]+1
      X[3]=X[3]-1
    } else if (j==19){
      X[4]=X[4]-1
      X[6]=X[6]+1
    } else if (j==20){
      X[4]=X[4]+1
      X[6]=X[6]-1
    } else if (j==21){
      X[4]=X[4]-1
      X[5]=X[5]+1
    } else if (j==22){
      X[4]=X[4]+1
      X[5]=X[5]-1
    } else if (j==23){
      X[2]=X[2]-1
      X[5]=X[5]+1
    } else if (j==24){
      X[2]=X[2]+1
      X[5]=X[5]-1
    } else if (j==25){
      X[3]=X[3]-1
      X[2]=X[2]+1
    } else if (j==26){
      X[3]=X[3]+1
      X[2]=X[2]-1
    } else if (j==27){
      X[3]=X[3]-1
      X[7]=X[7]+1
    } else if (j==28){
      X[3]=X[3]+1
      X[7]=X[7]-1
    } else if (j==29){
      X[8]=X[8]-1
      X[4]=X[4]+1
    } else if (j==30){
      X[8]=X[8]+1
      X[4]=X[4]-1
    } else if (j==31){
      X[4]=X[4]-1
      X[7]=X[7]+1
    } else if (j==32){
      X[4]=X[4]+1
      X[7]=X[7]-1
    } else if (j==33){
      X[6]=X[6]-1
      X[8]=X[8]+1
    } else if (j==34){
      X[6]=X[6]+1
      X[8]=X[8]-1
    } else if (j==35){
      X[3]=X[3]-1
      X[4]=X[4]+1
    } else if (j==36){
      X[3]=X[3]+1
      X[4]=X[4]-1
    }

    day.old <- day #Keep track of previous days
    day=ceiling(ti)
    if (day > day.old){ 
      saved[(day.old+1):day,] <- 
        matrix(saved[day.old,], (day - day.old), 8, byrow=TRUE) # What was this intended to achieve?
      saved[day,] <- X
      cat("day =", day, X, "\n")
      #cat('day:', sprintf('%7.4f',day.old), ' tail:', X[1], ' Anal:', X[2], ' LB:', X[3],' UB:',
      #    X[4],' Pelvic:', X[5],' Pectoral:', X[6],' dorsal:', X[7],' Head:', X[8], '\n')
    }
  }
  return(saved)   
}


#Suppose parasite prefer tail
b <- 0.5    #birth rate per day
d <- 0.14  #death rate  
m <- 0.3  #movement rate
X0 <- c(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)# initial condition of gyro that prefers the tail
Ti <- 17  #finishing time

#set.seed(12)
Results <- Fishsim_model(b, d, m, X0, Ti)
Results
```

Answer (score 0):

Both error messages suggest that at some point all values in the Q vector are 0, which causes the first error. Example : `sample(3,1, prob = c(0,0,0))`.

Consequently, the rate (Qt), which u are passing to the exponential distribution random generator is also 0 and NaN is returned, which causes the second error. Example : `rexp(1,0)`

Unfortunately, your code was hard for me to read, so I refactored it. You can find an augmented version below, which works with the example input. My guess  is that there is an error somewhere causing Q to take the 0 state, you can trace it with some print statements and debug functionalities. You can further refactor this piece of code to make it even more readable and performant.

In general, you can investigate the mathematical conditions for the initial inputs to guarantee that the Q vector never falls in the 0 state. I am not sure if you are looking for pointers on how to do this, as well.
HTH

```
CHANGE_MATRIX <- matrix(
  c(-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  , 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  , 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0
  , 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0
  , 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0
  , 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0
  , 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
  , 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0
  , 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  , 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
  , 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
  , 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0
  , 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1
  , 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1
  , 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0
  , 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0
  , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1
  , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1
  , 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
  , 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  , ncol = 8
  , byrow = T
)

UPDATE_LOCATION <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 5
                     , 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 7
                     , 8, 4, 4, 7, 6, 8
                     , 3, 4)

UPDATE_WEIGHT <- c(1, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2
                   , 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2
                   , 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2
                   , 4, 5)

UPDATE_INDEX <- seq(17, 36)

BODY_PARTS <- c(' Tail'
                ,' Anal'
                ,' LB'
                ,' UB'
                ,' Pelvic'
                ,' Pectoral'
                ,' dorsal'
                ,' Head')


Fishsim_model <- function(b,d,m,X0,Ti){
  #b=birth rate; d=death rate; m=movement rate; Ti=finishing time
  #X0=initial distribution; X= states 
  X <- X0
  Ti <- floor(Ti)
  ti <- 0 # (initial) time
  day <- 1

  saved <- matrix(0, Ti+1, 8) #Matrix of zeros to save final results
  saved[day,] <- X0

  Q <- vector('numeric', 36)
  Qt <- 0 # Qt = sum(Q) is departure rate from current state

  while (ti < Ti){
    #Calculate rates
    Q[1:8] <- X*b
    Q[9:16] <- X*d
    Q[UPDATE_INDEX]<-X[UPDATE_LOCATION[seq_along(UPDATE_INDEX)]]*
      (m*(1/UPDATE_WEIGHT[seq_along(UPDATE_INDEX)]))

    Qt <- sum(Q) 

    # time for next jump
    ti <- ti + rexp(1, Qt)

    # new state
    j <- sample(36, 1, prob = Q)

    if (j <= 8) {
      X[j] <- X[j] + 1
    } else if (j <= 16){
      X[j-8] <- X[j-8] - 1
    } else{
      X <- X + CHANGE_MATRIX[j-16, ]
    }


    day.old <- day #Keep track of previous days
    day <- ceiling(ti)

    if (day > day.old){

      # What was this intended to achieve?
      # saved[(day.old+1):day,] <- matrix(saved[day.old,]
      #                                   , (day - day.old)
      #                                   , 8
      #                                   , byrow=TRUE)

      saved[day, ] <- X
      cat(
          paste('day:', day)
          , '\n'
          , paste(BODY_PARTS, ':', X)
          , '\n'
      )

    }

  }

  return(saved)   
}


#Suppose parasite prefer tail
b <- 0.5    #birth rate per day
d <- 0.14  #death rate  
m <- 0.3  #movement rate
X0 <- c(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)# initial condition of gyro that prefers the tail
Ti <- 17  #finishing time

#set.seed(12)
Results <- Fishsim_model(b, d, m, X0, Ti)
Results
```

Comment: That was great. It seems to be working fine and everything is perfectly understood.

Comment: I tried to replicate the code for about 100 times just to see if such error as before would not appear. But it appears the error appears upon replication for say, 100 times. These are the errors produced when try at least 100 replications using replicate(100, Fishsim_model(b, d, m, X0, Ti)):                                                                                     Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  too few positive probabilities

Comment: My major problem was to find out how to prevent the Q vector from taking up 0 so as to avoid NAs when updating the time using the rexp(). It seems to persist after more than 10 runs.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to figure the way out to prevent the errors based previous recommendation received here. This will help me run the model a number of times without any error message. I just needed to break the loop from running when the sum of rates equals 0.
Below is the single code of line I needed to include in my codes;

```
enter code here


Qt=sum(Q)

if (Qt == 0) break #Just this line code to help break the loop and return to the next


ti <- ti + rexp(1,Qt)
j=sample(152,1,prob=Q)
```